# Bad Value error with my Google Apps Script to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

```
function tree1(){
  var secret =SpreadsheetApp.openById('My Database Secret') ;
  var sheet = secret.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var admin = data[i][0];
    var email = data[i][1];
    var name = data[i][2];
    var subject = data[i][3];
    var year = data[i][4];
    var testone = data[i][5];
    var testtwo = data[i][6];
    var testthree = data[i][7];
    var average = data[i][8];
    var progress = data[i][9];

    dataToImport[email] = {
      name:name,
      emailAddress:email,
      adminNo:admin,
      Subject:subject,
      Year:year,
      testOne:testone,
      testTwo:testtwo,
      testThree:testthree,
      Average:average,
      Progress:progress

      };
  }
  var firebaseUrl = "My Database URL";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  base.setData("", dataToImport);
}
```

I am attempting to use a Google Sheet App script to sync basic data for my users, using their email address as a reference.
So that when a user logs in with their email they can access test scores that the admin has.
The Database structure I would like is fairly simple that the three scores and other details are a child of the email, as you can see above.
However every time I attempt to complete the script I receive a Bad Value error.

Any ideas as to how I can remedy this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the [Firebase library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)?

Comment: It is installed, the error seems to come from the second line, where the error states Bad value (line 2, file "JsonTree")

Comment: Fixed the problem, I used the wrong API version on the library